# Customer comparator in postgresql that takes in two rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a sorting algorithm in kotlin which i am trying to implement in the order by function of a SQL query

```
private val comparator = Comparator<Person> { a, b ->
        if (a.x != null || b.x != null) {
            greaterThanOrEqualWithNull(a.x, b.x)
        } else greaterThanOrEqualWithNull(a.y, b.y)
    }

private fun greaterThanOrEqualWithNull(x: Int?, y: Int?): Int =
     if (x == b) 0
     else if (x == null) -1
     else if (y == null) 1
     else if (x > y) 1
     else -1
```

Essentially, a Person object in this case (a row in the DB) has two files (columns) x and y. Given two rows, if x is not null for either, i want to sort on x. otherwise sort on y. Keeping in mind that all values with an x value should come before those without.

I have tried something simple like this, which i would have hoped achieve this effect but it doesnt work, i think since it only has order logic for one row. I want to pass in a comparator that has two rows. Any help on how to do so?

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(x, y) ASC;
```

Example input output

Input:

```
// person(x?, y)
Person(13, 2)
Person(10, 5)
Person(null, 3)
Person(null, 7)
```

Output:

```
// person(x?, y)
Person(null, 3)
Person(null, 7)
Person(10, 5);
Person(13, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Realised i could solve my problem without a custom comparator

```
order by (a IS NOT NULL) desc, a desc, b desc
```